# ListView filled from AsyncTask doesn't render

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have a `Task` which extends Androids `AsyncTask` in order to get data from my Database in the cloud. I am doing this as to avoid `NetworkingOnMainThread` exception (I know you can set up `StrictMode` but in my opionion it's more of a hack than a solution).

I get no errors whatsoever. I have checked values in debugging and everything gets fetched correctly from my database. I have a `Venue` where I set my name, description, image etc... and the `ArrayList<Venue>` which I use for my adapter gets instantiated properly.

The problem is - the ListView doesn't render.

Here is my custom adapter code

```
public class EventListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
ArrayList<Venue> values;

public EventListArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Venue> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.single_event_list_item);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;

    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_event_list_item, null);
    }

    Venue currEvent = values.get(position);

    if(currEvent!=null){
        TextView singleItemTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemTitle);
        TextView singleItemLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemLocation);
        TextView singleItemDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemDate);
        ImageView singleItemImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.singleItemImage);

        singleItemTitle.setText(currEvent.getName());
        singleItemDate.setText(currEvent.getDate());
        singleItemLocation.setText(currEvent.getLocation());
        singleItemImage.setImageBitmap(currEvent.getVenueImage());
    }
    return v;
}

}
```

And here is my `AsyncTask` code

```
private class FillContentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ArrayList<Venue> venues;
    Context activity;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public FillContentTask(Context context) {
        this.activity = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        this.venues = Venue.getAll();
        for (Venue currentVenue : this.venues) {
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(currentVenue.getImageURL()).openStream();
                currentVenue.setVenueImage(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.eventList);
        EventListArrayAdapter adapter = new EventListArrayAdapter(activity, this.venues);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        dialog.hide();
    }
}
```

And as I already said. To the best of my knowledge, the AsnycTask does it's job properly since all `ArrayList<Venue> values` get filled properly

Comment: `getCount` method is missing. Try overriding it

Comment: heh it is done completly wrong ... instead `ArrayAdapter<String>` use `ArrayAdapter<Venue>`, instead   `Venue currEvent = values.get(position);`  use `getItem(position)`, get rid of constructor and private fields insted `context` use `getContext()` ... remeber about ViewHolder pattern, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `getCount` method in your `EventListArrayAdapter`

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
  return values.size();
}
```

OR

change the `super` call in EventListArrayAdapter constructor from

```
super(context, R.layout.single_event_list_item);
```

to

```
super(context, R.layout.single_event_list_item,values);
```

and also you will need to change `extends ArrayAdapter<String>` to `extends ArrayAdapter<Venue>`

Comment: Thanks man, works like a charm. Will accept when I'm allowed :)

Comment: the "OR" solution will not work since base class for `EventListArrayAdapter`  is `ArrayAdapter<String>` and `values` is type of `List<Venue>`

Comment: @Selvin Edited the answer. I missed that part.